# Why does this Regular Expression match nothing?

Tags: c#, regex

I want to replace all instances of all consecutive non-lowercase-alphabet-letters with a single space for each instance. This works, but why does it inject spaces in between the alphabet letters?

```
const string pattern = @"[^a-z]*";
const string replacement = @" ";
var reg = new Regex(pattern);

string a = "the --fat- cat";
string b = reg.Replace(a, replacement);  // b = " t h e  f a t  c a t " should be "the fat cat"
```

Comment: Use `+`, `@"[^a-z]+"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of `*`(which repeats the previous token **zero** or more times). It must finds a match in all boundaries since an empty string exists in all those boundaries.

```
const string pattern = @"[^a-z]+";
```

Comment: Well, not only :) `Regex.Replace` is also "to blame". Actually, OP pattern matches too much and this method finds and replaces all of them.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex if you simply want to remove non-lowercase letters:

```
string a = "the --fat- cat";
string res = String.Join("", a.Where(c => Char.IsLower(c) || Char.IsWhiteSpace(c)));

Console.WriteLine(res); // the fat cat
```

Comment: Yeah, but it will not contract mutliple whitespace symbols. A regex is still better for this task.

Answer (score 0):

Just a follow up answer  that might turn out useful: if you need to match any character but **any Unicode lowercase letter**, you may use

```
var res = Regex.Replace(str, @"\P{Ll}+", " ");
// "моя НЕ знает" > "моя знает"
```

The `\P{Ll}` construct will match all characters but lowercase letters from all Unicode table. The **`+` quantifier** will match *one or more occurrences* and will not cause the issue in OP.

And an [illustration of the current problem](https://regex101.com/r/eP0aH1/1) caused by `[^a-z]*` (see the vertical pipes showing where the `Regex.Replace` found empty string matches):

[image]

**A rule of thumb: *avoid* unanchored patterns that may match empty strings!**